# Is type constraint the same as implication in type space?

Tags: dependent-type, idris

In reading idris code, I sometimes wondered what's the mysterious type constraint `=>`.

It's said that dependent types are a first-class member of Idris. So can be we express type constraints such as `Eq a => Ord a` as some kind of function type in the function space `?? -> ??`? (here a function mapping a `Eq` to an `Ord`). Why do we need a separate operator?

The reason I ask is the small test below that I blundered into. If I declare a function `test` with an auto-implicit argument and then load it:

```
test: {auto flag : Int} -> Int
test = ?test_rhs
```

Instead of showing the original type, Idris2 (as of 0.7.0) will display be type of `test` as if it's a type constraint:

```
:t test
Idris.Main.test : Int => Int
```

*Is this a coincidence in syntax, or is it the case that fundamentally in dependent types, type constraints are a special form of implication `->` (i.e.  auto-implicits)?*

*If the latter case, how can one write parameterized things such as `Eq a => Ord a` as an implication (`->`) form?*

**-- Update --**

It seems that type constraints are exactly auto-implicit arguments with quantity 1.

Among the following three forms of implicit arguments, only the first one is treated as a type constraint `Eq a => Ord a`:

```
test1 : {auto x : Eq a} -> Ord a

test2 : {x : Eq a} -> Ord a

test3 : {auto 0 x: Eq a} -> Ord a
```

The others are shown as normal implicit arguments:

```
:t test1
Idris.Main.test1 : Eq a => Ord a
:t test2
Idris.Main.test2 : Ord a
:t test3
Idris.Main.test3 : {auto 0 _ : Eq a} -> Ord a
```

Comment: It might be worth learning about and comparing with Agda's instance arguments. There, it's made quite obvious that instance arguments elaborate to ordinary arguments (i.e, passing first class records around).

Comment: @JamesWood Thanks for the pointers. I'll have to learn Agda one of these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the point of view of logic, implicit arguments are indeed just arguments. In that sense, `Eq a => Ord a` is the same as the function space `Eq a -> Ord a`.

Always spelling out all arguments can be tedious, so as a programming language it's convenient to be able to elide some arguments as long as they can be inferred by some mechanism. You then need some notation to distinguish explicit from implicit arguments, that's why there are different arrows `->` and `=>`.